# Create Symbolic Function from Double Vector MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, vector, symbolic-math, data-fitting

I have a `1` by `T` double vector `X`, where `T = length(X)` is the number of timesteps. I would like to fit a symbolic time dependent function `sym F(t)` to this vector. What is the most efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: This seems like an  [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). what do you mean by *fit*ting? Why do you need a symbolic function?

Comment: I would like to use MATLAB's jacobian function on the vector which requires it to be a symbolic function. @SardarUsama

Comment: It’s not possible to specify an arbitrary length `t` vector symbolically. `t` must have a defined size.